# Modify value using form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a form to modify values that I take from a previous page.

What I don't understand is how save data in the state.

This is my code:

```
    class ModifyPerson extends Component {
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    firstname: this.props.location.state.firstname,
    lastname: this.props.location.state.lastname
    //they come from react-router-dom
    }
    }

handleChange(event){
// There I don't understand how to save every field in the state. So if the user modify the field 
// I would to save the new state.
}

    render(){
    return(
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
     <div>
            <label>FirstName</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="firstname"
              placeholder={this.state.firstname}
              value={this.state.firstname}
              onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(event)}
            />

            <label>LastName</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="lastname"
              placeholder={this.state.lastname}
              value={this.state.lastname}
              onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(event)}
            />
<button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">Send</button>
    </form>
    )}
    }
```

What I would to obtain: If the user change the field I would to save in the new state, if not the state remains the same that I have initialized in the constructor state. How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `setState`:

```
handleChange(event){
  this.setState({
    [event.target.name]: event.target.value
  })
}
```

and `handleSubmit`:

```
handleSubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(this.state.firstname, this.state.lastname);
};
```

Comment: I have tried this but when I modify the value I receive an error: cannot read property "firstaneme" of undefined

Comment: @Jack23 check this. https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-paper-udfrw . it works fine with just few changes in your code.

Comment: And why if in the handleSubmit I use console.log(this.state.firstname) it gives me the error?

Comment: Where is your `handleSubmit` ?

Comment: I don't have write because inside there is only a console.log but it is the submit form action